# How to reproduce a Java interface behaviour in a pythonic way

Tags: python, duck-typing

Let us define a class called `Filter`. I want this class to be extended by subclasses and I want all these subclasses to override a method : `job`.

More specifically

```
class Filter(object):
    def __init__(self, csvin=None):
        self._input = csvin

    # I want this to be abstract. All the classes that inherit from Filter should
    # implement their own version of job.
    def job(self):
        pass
```

Said differently, I want to make sure that any subclass of `Filter` has a method called `job`.

I heard about the module `abc`, but I also read about these concepts called duck-typing and EAFP. My understanding is that, if I am a duck, I will just try to run

```
f = SomeFilter()
f.job()
```

and see if it works. This is my problem if it raises any exception, I should have been more careful when I wrote the class `SomeFilter`.

I am pretty sure I do not fully understand the meaning of duck-typing and EAFP, but if it means that I have to postpone debugging as late as possible (that is, at invokation time), then I disagree with this way of thinking. I do not understand why so many people seem to appreciate this EAFP philosophy, but I wish to be part of them.

Can someone convert me and explain how to achieve this in a **safe** and **predictive** manner, that is by preventing the programmer from making a mistake when extending `Filter`, **in a pythonic way**.

Comment: You can't force this at compile time. You can, however, `raise NotImplementedError` in the base class's `job()` to indicate that the method has not been overridden when it should have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `raise NotImplementedError`, [as per the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NotImplementedError):

```
class Filter(object):
    def __init__(self, csvin=None):
        self._input = csvin

    # I want this to be abstract. All the classes that inherit from Filter should
    # implement their own version of job.
    def job(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```